# Passing An Array By Reference In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syntax

I would like to pass a NSMutableArray by reference so that it can be altered by another method. What would be the correct syntax for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Objective-C objects are always passed by reference (using pointers) - you can't pass them by value.

I.e. the following is fine:

```
- (void)mutateArray:(NSMutableArray*)array {
    // alter array ...
}
```

... and can be e.g. invoked like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;
[self mutateArray:array];
```

There is also the possibility of passing a pointer by reference:

```
- (void)newArray:(NSMutableArray **)array;
```

In that case `array` is used as an out-parameter - you pass a reference to a pointer to receive an instance:

```
- (void)newArray:(NSMutableArray **)array {
    *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

... which could be called like so:

```
NSMutableArray *array = nil;
[self newArray:&array];
```

Using out-parameters is usually only seen if the return-value is already used and additional information has to be returned. An example would be error-information as dreamlax noted.

Comment: What does it mean (using your above code as an example) when the following appears in a method declaration: `- (void)mutateArray:(NSMutableArray **)array;`?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Georg Fritzche's answer, it may be worth noting that some methods expect to be given the address of an object pointer. For example:

```
NSError *anError; // points to garbage now
NSStringEncoding enc;
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/some/file.txt"
                                          usedEncoding:&enc
                                                 error:&anError];

if (aString == nil)
{
    // anError now points to an initialised NSError object.
}
```

It gets tricky because some documented methods require you to release objects obtained in this manner, and some don't (for an example of one that does require explicit releasing, see [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/dataFromPropertyList:format:errorDescription:)).

Comment: Any method that requires you to release the returned pointer in this way *should* have explicit documentation, because it violates the fundamental rule of Cocoa reference counted memory management.

Answer (score 1):

As Georg Fritzsche said NSMutableArray passed be reference automatically, but not the NSArray. The best option is too look at the code bellow:

```
void mutateImmutableArray(NSArray *array);
void mutateMutableArray(NSMutableArray *array);
void mutateImmutableArrayByRef(NSArray **array);
void mutateMutableArrayByRef(NSMutableArray **array);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //Change immutable array in method that expects immutable array
        NSArray *immutable = @[@1,@2,@3];
        mutateImmutableArray(immutable);
        NSLog(@"After 1: %@",immutable); // 1,2,3

        //Change mutable array in method that expects immutable array
        NSMutableArray *mutable = [@[@1,@2,@3]mutableCopy];
        mutateImmutableArray(mutable); 
        NSLog(@"After 2: %@",mutable); //1,2,3

        //Change mutable array in method that expects mutable array
        mutable = [@[@1,@2,@3]mutableCopy];
        mutateMutableArray(mutable); 
        NSLog(@"After 3: %@",mutable); //1,2,3, Four

        //Change immutable array in method that expects immutable array by reference
        immutable = @[@1,@2,@3];
        mutateImmutableArrayByRef(&immutable); 
        NSLog(@"After 4: %@",immutable); //4,5,6

        //Change mutable array in method that expects mutable array by reference
        mutable = [@[@1,@2,@3]mutableCopy];
        mutateMutableArrayByRef(&mutable); 
        NSLog(@"After 5: %@",mutable); //1,2,3, Four

    }
    return 0;
}

void mutateImmutableArray(NSArray *array)
{
    array  = @[@4,@5,@6];
}

void mutateImmutableArrayByRef(NSArray **array)
{
    *array  = @[@4,@5,@6];
}

void mutateMutableArray(NSMutableArray *array)
{
    [array addObject:@"Four"];
}

void mutateMutableArrayByRef(NSMutableArray **array)
{
    [*array addObject:@"Four"];
}
```