# I have a Objective C function that takes any type of object by reference. But when i pass a NSMutableArray My function does not recognise It

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a function  That takes by reference any kind of object 
`-(BOOL)RemoteCall:(id**)DataClass;`
in the implementation i use [*DataClass isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableArray class] to find out the type of the object. The problem is it does not work with NSMUtableArrays Does anybody have a solution to this problem ? Here is the relevant code:

Implementation:

```
-(BOOL)RemoteCall:(id**)DataClass
{
    if([*DataClass isMemberOfClass:[NSMutableArray class] ] == YES)
    {
            NSMutableArray * SW =(NSMutableArray *)*DataClass;
                       //do something with SW
            DataClass= (id**)SW;
                        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Any help and I mean anything at all will be appreciated, I'm stuck.

```
Method Call:
NSMutableArray * channelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
Services * serv = [[Services alloc] init];
return [serv RemoteCall:&channelArray];
```

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused - what do you actually want to happen to `channelArray`? Do you want to change its contents or do you want to change what actual instance it points to by calling `RemoteCall`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Pass by reference in Objective-C is almost never the right way.

There are a number of problems with that code.

- `(id**)` is a *pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an object*.  Probably not at all what you want.
- `YES` and `NO` are `BOOL` return types;  not `TRUE`
- there is no reason in that code to be returning something by reference.
- method names start with lower case letters.  Arguments do, too.
- There will never be an instance of `NSMutableArray` in an application; just subclasses
- You can't tell the difference between a mutable and immutable array in the first place; check for `isKindOfClass:` or `isMemberOfClass:` for an `NSMutableArray` won't do you *much* good (it is useful, but misleading).

This is better:

```
-(BOOL)remoteCall: (id) dataThing
{
    if([dataThing isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]] == YES)
    {
            NSMutableArray *swArray = dataThing; // not strictly necessary, but good defensive practice
            //do something with swArray
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

To be called like:

```
NSMutableArray * channelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // you'll need to release this somewhere
Services * serv = [[Services alloc] init];
return [serv remoteCall:channelArray];
```

Since you don't return a different array in `remoteCall:`, `channelArray`'s contents will be manipulated by the method and the YES/NO return value.

If there is some reason why the above seemingly won't work for you, please explain why.

**Note:** The code obviously requires an `NSMutableArray` if you are going to muck with the contents.  The `isKindOfClass:` could be checking for `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray` and it wouldn't matter either way.  When using arrays in your code and requiring a mutable array, it is up to you to make sure the data flow is correct such that you don't end up w/an immutable array where you need a mutable array.

Comment: Very first line is super large and bold? Must be an answer from @bbum! ;)  (You'll also want to `release` the `serv` object...)

Comment: since trying to modify an NSArray throws an exception, IIRC, being able to test if an collection is mutable seems like it might be useful.  Care to explain the reasoning for why this isn't good practice?  (note that I've never felt the need to do this, just musing about ObjC here).

Comment: Sure; if you can differentiate between `NSArray*` and `NSMutableArray*`, then every API that returns an `NSArray` ends up having to return an autoreleased copy of the internal `NSMutableArray` oft used as a backing store.  Similarly, you end up w/code that does a lot of if-immutable-copy, but there is no way to fix up all references to the original immutable copy and, thus, object graph maintenance becomes an utter nightmare.

Comment: All good points, although "There will never be an instance of NSMutableArray in an application; just subclasses" *might* change whenever the implementor of the foundation classes feels like it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm new to Objective C started 3 weeks ago. Seems I have to learn a lot more. This answered a lot of questions. But what if i would need to use the array has an out-parameter (pass a reference to a pointer to receive an instance) just like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939695/passing-an-array-by-reference-in-objective-c  but for every type of object

Comment: It's also good defensive programming to compare with NO rather than YES -- the former is always zero, whereas the latter can take any number of other values, and who knows which second-hand third-party header may have redefined it?

Comment: @hatfinch Absolutely correct.   @Radu All objects are passed by reference; if you need to put something in a mutable array, pass the array as an argument and call `addObject:` in the receiver.  That is it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to reassign your variable, then don't use this. `id` or `NSObject *` is just fine and works by reference anyway. `id *` or `NSObject **` would be references. `id **` doesn't make sense at all here.

Also, learn naming conventions (like upper/lowercase).

Answer (score 4):

NSArray is a class cluster. That means that every NSArray instance is actually an instance of some subclass. Only isKindOfClass: is useful for class-membership testing with class clusters.

Also... thats horrible code - please accept this:

```
-(BOOL)remoteCall:(id)dataClass {
    if([dataClass isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
            NSMutableArray *sw =(NSMutableArray *)dataClass;
            return YES;
    }
}
```

that should work.

Constructive critisism of coding: You need to adhere to coding conventions. Although your code **will** work... its not brilliant to read and theres a lot of unnecessary *s and such.

Function names should be camel coded with a preceeding lower-case letter as should variable names. Passing (id) into a function doesn't require *s at all. Objects you pass into a function only available throughout the scope of the method anyway and that method doesn't own it, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with all the extra *s, but just treat objects you pass into the method as if you don't own them. :)

Comment: Might as well `return YES;`. But more importantly, you missed the "by reference" part :)

Comment: ah... missed that. return TRUE should still work, but in objc Georg is right - the proper way to work with BOOLs is YES and NO. Georg, you talking about passing vars into a method? Thats what I wanted to say, but couldn't think of the right words! :p

Comment: I thought he meant "passing `channelArray` by reference and making it point to another instance". But looking at it again i'm fully confused as to what he wants, so... ;)

Comment: from the look of his code it seems he just wants to return YES if the object is an NSMutableArray... :/ hes only returning a BOOL... :/ hmm i see what you mean though - i'm confused now. :p

Comment: yes i want to pass channelarray has a reference and keep the changes to it outside the method. all the pointers (**) i used are for using array has an out-parameter. I got the idea from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939695/passing-an-array-by-reference-in-objective-c

Comment: don't bother - just have a method that returns a mutable nsarray or something similar. :) its much easier. :)

Answer (score 2):

As Eiko said before, i'd use just id and not double pointers to ID.
I'm also pretty sure that `isMemberOfClass` is your Problem. isMember does not check for inheritance, so you're only asking for Top level Classes. `isKindOfClass` is probably the better choice, as there is no guarantee that Apple doesn't use an internal subclass of NSMutableArray internally. Check [the Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject).
i'd write it as such:

```
-(BOOL)RemoteCall:(id)dataClass
{
   if([dataClass isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class] ] == YES)
   {
       NSMutableArray * SW =(NSMutableArray *)dataClass;
       //do something with SW
       return TRUE;
   }
}
```

Comment: Change the `TRUE` to `YES` and add a `return NO;` at the end and this would be correct.  Note also that the methods are `isKindOfClass:`/`isMemberOfClass:` (the colon is significant).  Good answer save for these minor quibbles!