# Modify object passed into method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Let's say I've got this method:

```
-(void) mofidyObject:(NSArray *)obj;
```

How do I modify exactly the object which is passed into this array?

I've seen this some time and I know you need to have a "&" prefix, but don't know exactly how.

Comment: you can modify anything in this `obj` as it is just a pointer to ur object passed to this method..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

There's an object and then there's a variable that points to an object.  These are different and the ways to modify them are different.

If you want to modify the object (its content), that uses the normal passing mechanism that you have in your code -- except for the fact that NSArray is not a mutable object.  But if you'd passed a NSMutableArray instead, that would just work.

If you want to modify the content of the variable, to have it point to a **different** object, you have to pass its address to the method.  That's where the "&" operator comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) mofidyObject:(NSMutableArray **)obj
{
    [*obj addObject:@"love you!"];
}    

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Stack", @"Overflow", nil];
    [self mofidyObject:&array];

    //Don't forget to release after use
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrRows=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //suppose you have this NSMutableArray
[self mofidyObject:&arrRows];


}
-(void) mofidyObject:(NSMutableArray **)obj
{
    self.arrMultiProd=*obj; //Then you can assign pointer refrence to your NSMutableProperty like this
}
```

But Under ARC it will not allowed .

Answer (score 0):

There are relatively few circumstances where out-parameters like this are the best way of doing things in Cocoa.  Take a look at the frameworks for clues as when you should consider this pattern, e.g. `NSError` handling.

Other questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939695/passing-an-array-by-reference-in-objective-c) have addressed this pattern with mutable arrays.

That said, Objective-C is just a layer on top of C and can do whatever C can do.  To brush up on passing pointers by reference - take a look at this [excellent tutorial](http://masters-of-the-void.com/book6.htm) *(Masters of the Void, by Uli Kusterer)*