# Can I return two arrays?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to return two arrays using a custom method, is it possible in Objective-C?

I tried this:

```
-(nsmutablearray*, namutablearray*)someMethod{
  return (nsmutablearray*,namutablearray*)
}
```

Comment: instead of returning two array, return one array/Dictionary containing that two array

Comment: Either you concatenated them inside one array or one dictionary, or you could also do `-(void)someMethodArray1:(NSMutableArray **)array1 andArray2:(NSMutableArray **)array2`

Comment: Reopened because the selected duplicate wasn't remotely close to this question.

Comment: And closed with a proper duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

above function use on swift but if you want multi object pass, you need to 
Use this code:

Objective c:

```
-(NSArray*)somemethod{
    NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray new];
    return @[array1,array2];
}
```

Swift:

```
func somemethod() -> [AnyObject] {
        var array1 = [AnyObject]()
        var array2 = [AnyObject]()
        return [array1, array2]
    }
```

Comment: make you answer in proper formats with correct Array syntax instead of setting wrong return statement.

Comment: @NitinGohel..your answer was right. Y did u delete your answer?

Comment: Great answer. Just need to convert to swift:  func somemethod() -> [AnyObject] {
    var array1: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
    var array2: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
    return [array1, array2]
}

Comment: @PaulLehn Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

[image]No it's not possible. You can use follwoing code to achieve the same thing:

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self someMethosWithFirstArray:firstArray AndSecondArray:secondArray];
```

And use method like this:

```
-(void) someMthodWithFirstArray:(NSMutableArray *) firstArray AndSecondArray:(NSMutableArray *) secondArray {
// update arrays and it will reflect
}
```

Comment: This will not work as you have not passed the reference of the arrays.

Comment: Please see this line in code: [self someMethosWithFirstArray:firstArray AndSecondArray:secondArray]; Here the reference of both arrays are bring passed :)

Comment: Nope you are passing array not their references remember that

Comment: Parameters are always passed as reference. It will not create the separate arrays. You can try by running the code.

Comment: You can go through link here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2939702/4321357

Comment: Look carefully in the link you have posted. It mentions the same thing that parameters are always passed by reference. :)

Comment: Objective-C objects are always passed by reference (using pointers) - you can't pass them by value.

Comment: You here need to pass the pointer of an array read it carefully bro

Comment: And this is the wrong way to achieve the functionality, you should return array instead of manipulating them

Comment: @AadilKeshwani please have a look at me tested code snippet